# CSS puzzle: making a select2 box 100% width in a fluid-width div?

Tags: css

I am using the awesome [Select2 jQuery plugi](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)n.

Currently I have a fixed-width div floating to the left of a fluid-width div, this works well:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col left">Label</div>
<div class="col right"></div>
</div>
.row {
    display: table;
}
.col {
    display: table-cell;
}
.col.left {
    width: 150px
}
```

But it doesn't work so well when I add a select2 box inside the fluid right div. Now it becomes clear that the fluid right div is not actually 100% width, it adapts to the width of its content, and as a result the select2box also changes size constantly:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col left">Label</div>
<div class="col right"><select style="width: 100%" class="select2">
```

Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/vfa4831b/4/

How can I make the `.right` fluid-width div adapt to the width available, and stay at that size?

Adding `width: 100%;` to `.col.right` makes the div 100% width, but also overflows the boundaries of `.row`.

UPDATE: I need IE8 support, unfortunately, so can't just use `calc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Your row that uses `display: table` wasn't actually being set to be 100%.